# Load files from resource beans?

Tags: java, itext

I want to load some fonts and use them with Itext.

I saved the font in the `/resources/font/` folder. I tried to load them this was

```
BaseFont verdana_bf = BaseFont.createFont("../resources/font/Calibri.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

but it does not work, I get following error:

```
java.io.IOException: ../resources/font/Calibri.ttf not found as file or resource.
```

How can I load fonts, images from the resource folder in my beans? I need to load some images aswell.

Comment: Are you sure your current working directory shares the same parent directory with `resources`? And do you have the required permissions to access that folder structure?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
    Myclass.class.getResource("/font/calibri.ttf");

For this the resources folder needs to be added to the build path.